# Match a string in a string containing certain string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

Sorry for the awful title - not sure how best to put it.

note:
Am trying to do this in Javascript

I want to match specific text within 2 different urls which are of differing length and structure.  One starts with `video` and the other with say `audio`.  The match must be replaced differently depending on the start of the string.

I can't work out how to make a dotall (.*) match in a positive lookbehind?

For example, the strings below ought to be matched by 2 separate RegEx's, one specifying that `video` and the other `audio` must be before `%7bmatch%7d`
They must **only** match `%7bmatch%7d` for the given string beginning.

```
video://lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length/%7bmatch%7d/lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length

audio://lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length/%7bmatch%7d/lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length
```

I have tried:
`/(?<=video)(?<=.*)%7bmatch%7d/g` http://regexr.com?373gh
amongst other variants and can't quite seem to only match the `%7bmatch%7d` or any other match without getting everything since `video` in the example.
Got me stumped, would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

**EDIT:** Answer specific to Javascript:

```
// Random collection of string(s)
var inputString = "video://lots0fr@ndomcharacasdf/asd/ft#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length/%7bmatch%7d/lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@lengthaudio://lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbet/asdfas/dweenof1nd1scrimin@length/%7bmatch%7d/lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@lengthvideo://lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweasdf/asd/f/asdfenof1nd1scrimin@length/%7bmatch%7d/lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@lengthaudio://lots0fr@ndomcharaasdfafsdct#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length/%7bmatch%7d/lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@lengthvideo://lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinfasdfasdfbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length/%7bmatch%7d/lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@lengthaudio://lots0fr@ndomcharaasdfasdf///asdfasdfct#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length/%7bmatch%7d/lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length";



// Regex to match after every `video` occurence
regexVideo = new RegExp(/(video.*?)%7bmatch%7d/g);

// Regex to match after every `audio` occurence
regexAudio = new RegExp(/(audio.*?)%7bmatch%7d/g);

// strings to replace the matches
var replaceStringVideo = "<span class='woot'>W00tW00tVideoW00t</span>";
var replaceStringAudio = "<span class='woot'>W00tW00tVAudioW00t</span>";

// replace both audio and video with respective replace values NOTE: the dollar token needed concatenated before the replaceString.
inputString.replace(regexVideo, "$1" + replaceStringVideo).replace(regexAudio, "$1" + replaceStringAudio);

// This yields an inputString value of 
"video://lots0fr@ndomcharacasdf/asd/ft#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length/<span class='woot'>W00tW00tVideoW00t</span>/lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@lengthaudio://lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbet/asdfas/dweenof1nd1scrimin@length/<span class='woot'>W00tW00tVAudioW00t</span>/lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@lengthvideo://lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweasdf/asd/f/asdfenof1nd1scrimin@length/<span class='woot'>W00tW00tVideoW00t</span>/lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@lengthaudio://lots0fr@ndomcharaasdfafsdct#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length/<span class='woot'>W00tW00tVAudioW00t</span>/lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@lengthvideo://lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinfasdfasdfbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length/<span class='woot'>W00tW00tVideoW00t</span>/lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@lengthaudio://lots0fr@ndomcharaasdfasdf///asdfasdfct#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length/<span class='woot'>W00tW00tVAudioW00t</span>/lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length"
```

Comment: What language or tool are you using ?

Comment: Will be using javascript if I can get it working at regexr.com

Comment: Its not working on regexr because it doesn't seem to support variable length lookbehinds. If you change .* to .{x} where x is the exact number of characters it would match.

Comment: Why do you only want `%7bmatch%7d` to match?

Comment: @SQB because I want to be able to replace it.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker It doesn't make sense that you want to match `%7bmatch%7d`. I mean if you already know what you want then why do you use it in your regex ? I'm wondering if you want to replace the first "string" that appears between `/`. For example if you want to match `foobar` in `video://sjfdsfdsfdsfsd/foobar/shfdshdsfs` ?

Comment: @HamZa There many of these strings and the `match` needs to be replaced differently depending on the start of the string.  Hence I want to only match/replace the `match` with one regex for say the `video` prefix and then another one for `audio`.  Is there a better way to do it if there is a document/data full of these strings?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker You can match more than what you want to replace, see my updated answer.

Comment: @HamZa sorry, there are more slashes in the indiscriminate string. however.  In theory if there's the last one before my intended `match` can I somehow use that in a javascript based regex with a lookbehind including discriminating between `audio` and `video`?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker There is no lookbehinds in JS. It's really unclear what you want. So the only hint I could give you is the following : there is a workaround, for example you want to replace `foo` if there is a `lol` behind it, you just match everything from `lol` to `foo` and put it in a group` : `(lol.*)foo` and replace it with `$1bar`. The `foo` will be replaced by `bar` if there is a `lol` behind it. Ofc, take in account that `.` doesn't match newlines, so to go around that you use `[\s.]` instead of `.`. Hope this helps ....

Comment: @SQB I get what you're saying, is there a way you can get your updated answer to work at http://regex101.com/#javascript ? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @HamZa Many thanks for that - So there is no way to do this on a case-by-case (audio vs video) string in JS?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I've updated my answer again.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I just provided you the workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug on that website. You should use `/(?<=video.*)%7b.*?%7d/g`, but that website seems to think it's a lookahead, not a lookbehind (you can check it by hovering over either parenthesis).

---

If you need to match `%7b.*?%7d` to replace it, just match everything up to it and refer to that in your replacement, like this:

`s/^(video.*?)%7b.*?%7d/$1your_replacement_here/g`

See [demo on regexr.com](http://regexr.com?373hf) and another [demo on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/qF2zP1).

Comment: JS doesn't support lookbehinds. And most engines don't even support infinite lookbehinds like you suggest.

Comment: @SQB The site does have it's tootltips muddled I agree however the lookahead/lookbehind examples work as expected, just the tooltips are wrong.

Comment: Yeah, only saw just now that asker wants to use JavaScript. And example had lookbehind in it, so I assumed that it was in a dialect that supported lookbehinds.

Comment: @SQB - Many thanks that seems to have done the trick with a bit of refactoring for JS ;) +1 http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/zHQAZ/embedded/result/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP or Perl then you can use the `\K` anchor to ignore everything matched before it in the regular expression like this:

```
video.*\K%7bmatch%7
```

In JavaScript unfortunately the easiest way would be to use the following regular expression which would match everything from video until `%7bmatch%7d`, then you can use `replace()` to get rid of the un-needed data:

```
var input = "video://lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length/%7bmatch%7d/lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length";
var finalResult = /(?=video.*%7bmatch%7d).*%7bmatch%7d/.exec(input)[0].replace(/.*(?=%7bmatch%7d)/, "");
console.log(finalResult);
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yK8fG4)

Comment: @RobSchmuecker You are welcome, but be careful that JavaScript doesn't support the `\K` anchor nor look behinds.

Comment: ah I've just noticed that - any tips on getting it to work in JS?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I am really sorry, but I have to go right now. If I got back soon I will try to post a working solution in JavaScript. Again really sorry.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I have edited my answer to include a solution for JavaScript.

Comment: Many thanks for all your efforts - here's the reason why I've given best answer to @SQB http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/zHQAZ/embedded/result/
Thanks for all your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker You are welcome, you can choose whatever solves your problem the best way possible :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this RegExp:

```
var regExpVideo = /(?:video):\/\/[^%]+([^\/]+)/
var regExpAudio = /(?:audio):\/\/[^%]+([^\/]+)/
var videoSource = regExpVideo.exec("video://lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length/%7bmatch%7d/lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length")[1];
var audioSource = regExpAudio.exec("audio://lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length/%7bmatch%7d/lots0fr@ndomcharact#Rsinbetweenof1nd1scrimin@length")[1];
```

Hope this helps,

Regards,

Marcelo

Comment: Hi Mindastic, many thansk for your answer, here's the reason I'm accepting @SQB's answer http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/zHQAZ/embedded/result/

Comment: Hi Rob. I just updated my answer because when i wrote it, i wanted to use exec instead of match. I don't know why i used match because match is for strings not for regexp. Anyway, i am glad to read that you get a useful answer :). Rgds.